# How do I fix "E:Type 'b-src' is not known on line 'X' in source list" error?

Tags: updates, package-management, ppa, software-sources

This is the error I'm getting from using `sudo apt-get update`

```
E:Type 'b-src' is not known on line 2 in source list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tiheum-equinox-precise.list
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Almost agree with @qbi. I assume it's supposed to be `deb-src`.

Comment: Just edit that file using gedit: `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tiheum-equinox-precise.list`. The line 2 should be something like `deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu precise main`

Comment: I can't seem to get access to gksu, Is there another workaround?

Comment: Enter in you terminal `sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tiheum-equinox-precise.list` then copy the content of the file and upload it here.

Comment: I'm using another computer, but after typing that code in it opened gedit were I saw 2 lines, first with # sign and the second line without. Should I delete the second line?

Comment: The file should have `deb-src` at the begging of the second line.

Comment: It's working, thank you very much 'Lucio' and 'Salem'. I'll create an answer for future references.

Comment: Opps can't answer my own question, but here is the solution.Thanks to **Salem** and **Lucio** for helping in solving this.

You have to open terminal and type in; 

> sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/tiheum-equinox-precise.list 

Press enter, you then edit by adding 

> **deb**-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/tiheum/equinox/ubuntu 

In this case replacing 'b' from the start of the line with 'deb'

Answer (score 2):

This error advertise is telling you that the concerned file (`tiheum-equinox-precise.list` in this case) have the `b-src` phrase, and that is wrong because *it should be* `deb-src` instead.

So you have tree options to solve the issue:

1. **Fix the line with the typing problem:**
   Open the file, find the line with `b-src` and replace it with this one: `deb-src`
2. **Convert the line in a comment:**
   Open the file, find the line with `b-src` and add the `#` character at the begging of this line
3. **Delete the file:**
   Enter the next command in a terminal: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/your_file`

**NOTE**: *To open the file, enter the following command in a terminal:*
`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list.d/your_file`

Now you will be able to update your system!

Comment: @frqcuse You can [mark the answer as accepted](http://meta.askubuntu.com/q/1137/62483), leaving this question as *answered*..